# What is the difference between VS2010 and VS2010 Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open some of my visual studio 2010 workflow projects in Visual studio 2010 shell which I have but those projects are not opening for me.

I want to know the exact difference between both VS2010 and VS2010 Shell?
why I am not able to open my projects in VS2010 Shell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is Visual Studio 2010 Shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019306/what-is-visual-studio-2010-shell)

Comment: I want to know what is the difference between them? and when and who should use vs2010 and vs2010 shell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019306/what-is-visual-studio-2010-shell